# JMockit - Instance of class to be tested is null

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

So I have began using JMockit and JUnit to test my code.

I wrote a class and wanted to test that class. The class is as follows -

```
public final class KingdomDAOImpl implements KingdomDAO {

private Map<KingdomType, Kingdom> kingdomEmblemMap;

@Inject
public KingdomDAOImpl(final Map<KingdomType, Kingdom> kingdomEmblemMap) {
    this.kingdomEmblemMap = kingdomEmblemMap;
}

@Override
public Map<KingdomType, Kingdom> getKingdoms() {
    return kingdomEmblemMap;
}
}
```

And my test class looks like this -

```
public class KingdomDAOTest {

@Injectable
private static Map<KingdomType, Kingdom> kingdomEmblemMap;

@Tested
private static KingdomDAOImpl kingdomDAO;

@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() {
    kingdomEmblemMap = new HashMap<>();
}

@Test
public void getKingdomsTest() {
    System.out.println("=========+> " + kingdomDAO);
    final Map<KingdomType, Kingdom> actualKingdomEmblemMap = kingdomDAO.getKingdoms();

    Assert.assertEquals(kingdomEmblemMap, actualKingdomEmblemMap);
}
}
```

Now, the problem that I'm having is that the `kingdomDAO` instance is `null`, which I am not able to understand why. Due to this, `kindomDAO.getKingdoms()` throws a `NullPointerException`.

Any ideas on how to proceed from here?

EDIT: I was using JMockit version `1.8`. I have tried upgrading to `1.45` and replacing `@Injectable` annotation with `@Tested`, but still the same problem persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JMockit has changed a bit since the last time I used it.
What I can recommend to you is, **always read the release notes**!

Version 1.42

> JMockit now requires the use of the "-javaagent" JVM initialization
>   parameter

Version 1.45

> Mocking annotations (@Mocked, @Capturing, and @Injectable) can no
>   longer be used on Java SE collection and map interfaces, for two
>   reasons: 1) on Java 8+, such interfaces include default methods, which
>   do get mocked, easily causing unexpected results in tests; 2) mocking
>   of said interfaces (and more generally, of all value-oriented types
>   which basically encapsulate state without complex behavior in methods)
>   is a well known bad practice. In the particular case of having an
>   @Injectable collection/map field which is meant to be injected into a
>   @Tested object, the test should be changed to use @Tested as well on
>   the collection/map field, with its declaration positioned before the
>   target @Tested field.

---

Although I **wouldn't** code a test like that, the working example is:

```
public class KingdomDAOtest {
    @Tested
    Map<KingdomType, Kingdom> kingdomEmblemMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Tested
    KingdomDAOImpl kingdomDAO;

    @Test
    public void getKingdomsTest() {
        System.out.println("=========+> " + kingdomDAO);
        final Map<KingdomType, Kingdom> actualKingdomEmblemMap = kingdomDAO.getKingdoms();

        Assert.assertEquals(kingdomEmblemMap, actualKingdomEmblemMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the release notes, should have read them. Also, I should have mentioned in my question that the version I am using is `1.8` which I realize is really old. After updating the version to `1.45` and using the snippet provided by you, the `kingdomDAO` is still `null`, giving me a `NullPointerException` while calling it's method, any idea?

Comment: @AkshanshJain using 1.45, you need to start your JVM with -javaagent:path-to-jmockit.jar. On 1.8 you need to use the class annotation RunWith(JMockit.class)

Comment: Extremely sorry for the late reply man. Yes, I was able to solve it using `@RunWith(JMockit.class)` at the top of my class. Although, the project I am working on currently uses JMockit 1.8 as well, but there we are not providing such annotations over test classes, which I was trying to figure out and got lost. So, the problem is solved and the solution was to use the annotation in my case. Thanks man!